# My App Icon is not showing on Game Center

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

My game (called uDivideGood) is on Game Center and everything is working fine in terms of the leaderboard scores etc.  The only problem is that Game Center is not showing my app's icon where it's supposed to.  My game's "page" on Game Center just shows the name of the game and all the scores in the leaderboard but the space for the icon is blank, as well as the space for the icon in the list of games.  I looked on my itunesconnect page and didn't find any place to add an icon for Game Center and I know I uploaded all the images with the binary.  Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**You need to include a special icon in the size of 29x29 (58x58) in the app bundle!**

Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html) for more info about app icons.

If that's not the case check you Xcode build on your iPhone & simulator! Is the icon still there?

Look for the little mistakes:

1. Spelled the image name wrong
2. Image has the wrong size (e.g. 60x60)
3. Image is not in bundle

If it's still not working, try this:

Remove the asset folder from the project and then create a new asset catalog. Close the project. Move the old json and png files to below new asset catalog folders. Reopen Xcode.

That's everything I can suggest you to do.

Cheers